# Passing an object an array of it's own promises functions to be executed in series?

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, es6-promise, es6-class

I would like to achieve the following: I have a class generating an object with a series of methods.
Each of these is likely to be a promise.

From the outside of it should be possible to pick these methods and compose them into an array and ask the same object to execute them in series.

The code should be something like this (of course this does not work, this is why I'm asking):

```
class Car{
 constructor(){}

 fuctionA(input){
  // do stuffs 
 }
 fuctionB(input){
  // do stuffs 
 }
 fuctionC(input){
  // do stuffs 
 }
 fuctionD(input){
  // do stuffs 
 }
 executeArrayOfFuctions(array){
  // execute each function in the array when the previous is resolved
 }
}

const car1 = new Car();
const car2 = new Car();

const arrayOfFunctions = [functionA(input), functionC(input), functionA(input)];

car1.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
car2.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
```

EDIT: The reason because I pass an arbitrary order of functions from outside the object is because I want to be able to have different combinations of those functions every time.
Like for example a choreography, where you can have many dancers able to perform a number of movements, but not always the same, and not the same for everyone.
Sorry, this was not specified well enough.

EDIT: for @Akshay Bande, I do like how you pass a string reference to the internal methods, but still if I try to really go ahead and defines my methods as promises, with a 1-second timeout to be resolved, they are executed all at once.
I did not really get the Promise.resolve() part.

```
class Car {
  constructor() {}

  functionA(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("A", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionB(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("B", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionC(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("C", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionD(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("D", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  executeArrayOfFuctions(array) {
    let p = Promise.resolve();

    array.forEach(val => {
      p = p.then(() => {
        this[val.functionName](val.arg);
        return Promise.resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}

const car1 = new Car();
const car2 = new Car();

const arrayOfFunctions = [
  { functionName: "functionA", arg: "1" },
  { functionName: "functionC", arg: "2" },
  { functionName: "functionA", arg: "3" }
];

car1.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
//car2.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
```

3EDIT:
Thanks @AkshayBande for your help, I think this way can work:

```
class Car {
  constructor() {}

  functionA(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("A", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionB(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("B", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionC(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("C", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionD(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("D", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  async executeArrayOfFuctions(array) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      await this[array[index].functionName](array[index].arg);
    }
  }
}

const car1 = new Car();
const car2 = new Car();

const arrayOfFunctions = [
  { functionName: "functionA", arg: "1" },
  { functionName: "functionC", arg: "2" },
  { functionName: "functionA", arg: "3" }
];

car1.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
//car2.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
```

Or like this:

```
class Car {
  constructor() {}
  functionsStack = [];

  addFunctionA(input) {
    this.functionsStack.push({ fn: "functionA", args: input });
    return this;
  }
  addFunctionB(input) {
    this.functionsStack.push({ fn: "functionB", args: input });
    return this;
  }
  addFunctionC(input) {
    this.functionsStack.push({ fn: "functionC", args: input });
    return this;
  }
  addFunctionD(input) {
    this.functionsStack.push({ fn: "functionD", args: input });
    return this;
  }
  functionA(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("A", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionB(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("B", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionC(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("C", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  functionD(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("D", input);
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  start() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.executeArrayOfFuctions(this.functionsStack).then(() => {
        this.functionsStack = [];
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
  async executeArrayOfFuctions(array) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      await this[array[index].fn](array[index].args);
    }
  }
}

const car1 = new Car();
const car2 = new Car();
car1
  .addFunctionA("1")
  .addFunctionB("2")
  .addFunctionC("3")
  .addFunctionA("5")
  .addFunctionD("6")
  .addFunctionB("7")
  .start()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(car1.functionsStack);
  });

// const arrayOfFunctions = [
//   { functionName: "functionA", arg: "1" },
//   { functionName: "functionC", arg: "2" },
//   { functionName: "functionA", arg: "3" }
// ];

// car1.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
//car2.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
```

Comment: your `arrayOfFunctions` is better called `arrayOfResultsOfCallingFunctions` - because that's what it is :p

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the example. Is C dependent on A? It must be, because A is repeated. How can A fetch something with the same input and expect any other answer than from the first time it's called? Is the `input` something that is constantly changed?

Comment: You can do it like your 3rd edit @piLeoni

Answer (score 0):

No, don't make it that complicated. With `async`/`await`, you don't need to pass functions around. Also the `Car` object should not be responsible for being able to run async functions sequentially - that's the job of a simple helper function if you really needed it. But just write

```
class Car {
  constructor() {}

  async functionA(input) {
    // do stuffs 
  }
  async functionB(input) {
    // do stuffs 
  }
  async functionC(input) {
    // do stuffs 
  }
  async functionD(input) {
    // do stuffs 
  }
}

async function go(car) {
  await car.functionA(input);
  await car.functionC(input);
  await car.functionA(input);
}

go(new Car()); // car 1
go(new Car()); // car 2
```

Comment: What happens if you want the order to be functionB, functionC, functionA at one time, and something else another time?

Comment: @RickardElimää Then write a different function. Or is the order dynamic? If so, how is it selected, and how are the items represented?

Comment: Whenever I write an answer, I always assume dynamic.

Comment: @RickardElimää Oh, sorry, I mistook you for the OP. I really doubt he needs a dynamic solution, we should start simple instead.

Comment: Why would s/he otherwise bring up function D and not use it in the example? To me, it's just bad coding standard to hardcode for one possible situation.

Comment: @RickardElimää Given that the input `arrayOfFunctions = [functionA(input), functionC(input), functionA(input)];` is invalid syntax, we don't even know what kind of problem the OP has, and I won't write an answer based on guesswork. But since they seem to lack the very basics, I'd write an answer that starts with that.

Comment: Actually what I am looking for it is a dynamic solution, I wrote an edit to make it more clear, sorry if this was initially not.

Comment: @piLeoni If you really need an array as input (of strings with method names, of objects with names and arguments, or maybe just async functions to be executed) - just loop through them and call your methods with `await`.

Comment: @piLeoni However, I'm not quite sure about your example "*a choreography, where you can have many dancers able to perform a number of movements*". If those dance moves are to be programmed, not configured by the author, then an `async function` like my `go` would be the most natural representation for a series of moves. You can build an entire choreography of functions calling each other (possibly even concurrently with `Promise.all`). Without knowing your actual use case I still believe that there's no need for [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)).

Comment: @Bergi, I see your point but my goal is to create an interface to test a series of different effects and sequences, without having to deal with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are what you need.

```js
class Car{

constructor(){}

functionA(input){
// do stuffs 
console.log(input);
}

functionB(input){
// do stuffs 
console.log(input);
}

functionC(input){
// do stuffs 
console.log(input);
}

functionD(input){
// do stuffs 
console.log(input);
}

executeArrayOfFuctions(array){
// execute each function in the array when the previous is resolved

let p = Promise.resolve();

array.forEach((val)=>{

  p = p.then(()=>{

    this[val.functionName](val.arg);   
    return Promise.resolve();
  })
})

}
}

const car1 = new Car();
const car2 = new Car();

const arrayOfFunctions = [ {functionName: 'functionA', arg:'1'},{functionName: 'functionC', arg:'2'}, {functionName: 'functionA', arg:'3'} ];

car1.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
//car2.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
```

Comment: Your function doesn't use the array?

Comment: hi, I added an edit to better explain, the problem of this is that does not allow me to re-arrange the order of methods I want to be executed in sequence.

Comment: @piLeoni I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @AkshayBande, it is a progress but still it execute all at once the promises, I've updated the code for having actually all functions as promises resolving after one second.

Comment: @piLeoni you want to execute functions in the same order you pass to `executeArrayOfFunctions`?

Comment: You don't have to define your methods as promises, you should use promise in `executeArrayOfFunctions` only to execute functions in the order you want. Please keep your methods as they were and just change the `arrayOfFunctions` array to array of objects so that you can pass function name and function argument to `executeArrayOfFunctions`,

Comment: Your code is executing all at once cause promises are getting resolved immediately.

Answer (score 0):

According to edit added to the question, If you want to execute functions after one-second delay then you can use this code.

```js
class Car {
constructor() {}

delay(time){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve();
    },time)
  })
}

functionA(input) {
  this.delay(1000).then(()=>{
    console.log('A');
  })
}

functionB(input) {
   this.delay(1000).then(()=>{
    console.log('B');
  })
}

functionC(input) {
  this.delay(1000).then(()=>{
    console.log('C');
  })
}

functionD(input) {
  this.delay(1000).then(()=>{
    console.log('D');
  })
}

executeArrayOfFuctions(array) {
  let p = Promise.resolve();

  array.forEach(val => {
    p = p.then(() => {
      this[val.functionName](val.arg);
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
  });
}
}

const car1 = new Car();
const car2 = new Car();

const arrayOfFunctions = [
{ functionName: "functionA", arg: "1" },
{ functionName: "functionC", arg: "2" },
{ functionName: "functionA", arg: "3" }
];

car1.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
//car2.executeArrayOfFuctions(arrayOfFunctions);
```